# pictures from mixitup jQuery plugin does not always load in ie11

Tags: jquery, html

have an annoying problem and i dont really know what to look for anymore
my website loads perfect in everyweb browser except internet explorer (I`m using 11).

The problem is that the img used in the mixitup filter does not always load in ie 11.
All other pictures do load fine(the ones not used with mixitup)

It seems its random.
AQbout 20% of the time i get red beems with the alternate text FOOD inside of it.
When i refresh a couple of times the pictures suddenly appear,
80% of the time it loads perfectly

```
 <section class="description_content">
        <div class="limit"> 
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div id="w">

                        <ul id="filter-list" class="clearfix">
                            <li class="filter" data-        filter="breakfast">Lunch</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-    filter="special">Dinner</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-    filter="desert">Diversen</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-    filter="dinner">Nagerechten</li>
                        </ul><!-- @end #filter-list -->    
                        <ul class="row" id="portfolio">
                            <li class="item breakfast"><img     src="images/lunch.jpg" alt="Food" >

                                <li class="item special"><img     src="images/dinner.jpg" alt="Food" >

                            <li class="item desert"><img     src="images/food_icon07.jpg" alt="Food" >

                            </li>
                            <li class="item dinner"><img     src="images/nagerechten.jpg" alt="Food" >

                            </li>

                         </ul><!-- @end #portfolio -->
                    </div><!-- @end #w -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </section>
```

Because a lot of people still use ie I would love for it to work 100% of the time.
I dont really have an idea where to look for what is causing it.
Do you guys have any idea how to fix something like this?
why does it loads fine on all other browsers?
Thanks for your time
Sorry for my bad spelling

Have tried f12 tools and got
1 error acces denied script5 line 1 column 1, but it gives that same error with or without the pictures in mixitup loading

network stats on the pictures
URL Protocol    Methode Resultaat   Type    Ontvangen   Gebruikt    Initiator   Wachten‎‎   Begin‎‎ Aanvraag‎‎  Antwoord‎‎  Cache gelezen‎‎ Hiaat‎‎
file:///C:/Users/fixed/Documents/gasthuys/images/lunch.jpg  file        (Bestand)       0 B < 1 ms     16  0   0   0   0   6630
file:///C:/Users/fixed/Documents/gasthuys/images/dinner.jpg file        (Bestand)       0 B < 1 ms     16  0   0   0   0   6630
file:///C:/Users/fixed/Documents/gasthuys/images/food_icon07.jpg    file        (Bestand)       0 B < 1 ms     16  0   0   0   0   6630
file:///C:/Users/fixed/Documents/gasthuys/images/nagerechten.jpg    file        (Bestand)       0 B < 1 ms     16  0   0   0   0   6630

Comment: Seems like a server error. You should use IE F12 tools to see network request stats. Try it and update your question with results.

Comment: I should have stated that i did not upload it yet, I am previewing the index.html from dreamweaver. could it still be that then

Comment: You can see your site locally and still use IE tools.

Comment: I never used it before , It gives 1 error acces denied script5 line 1 column 1, but it gives that same error with or without the pictures in mixitup loading

Comment: Update your question with detailed error message. Also add network stats on images.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx) may help.

Comment: So it is access denied javascript error, you need post javascript that throws this error.

Comment: Sorry for all the dumb questions but is that the wrong file? I really have no idea, thats the only js file that came with mixitup afaik

Comment: Ok, got it. Better delete it from the question. I think the error is in "file" protocol. Try to use local web server or upload it to test server.

Comment: I installed apache and in localhost it open up correct everytime so far.Does that mean it will work if i upload it to my server?  It look like you saved my day :) Thank you very much

Comment: I will post answer with solution then. And yes, it will work if you upload it to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in "file" protocol. Try to use local web server or upload it to test server.